# What fraction of known scriptures has been scanned and stored digitally?

Tags: untagged

The best quality manuscript of the Paippalada recension of the Atharva Veda was discovered only in 1957.  I believe there is a large number of palm-leaf manuscripts that have not yet been scanned and digitized.  There must be other manuscripts in existence not known yet.

Major scriptures like the Itihasas and Puranas exist in multiple versions  and bodies like BORI have prepared Critical Editions of some of them to filter out interpolations and incorporate all the known original materials.

Is any religious/government body working on preserving these manuscripts before they get lost?

Comment: Two persons from IITB, Acharya Ramasubrahmanyam and Prof Malhar Kulkarni are doing great work to preserve the manuscripts. Acharya Ramasubrahmanyam has done work in the field of Indian science also

Comment: Yes there are many such organizations. For example, in my native place of Kolkata, the Asiatic Society, Calcutta University & Sanskrit University are repositories of a large amount of manuscripts. Dhaka University & Rajshahi University (mostly the collection of the Varendra Research Organisation) also have a decent amount of Sanskrit manuscripts. Nepal Durbar library is also an impressive repository. Some manuscripts have even gone to Europe. A few months ago, I came across a manuscript of the Hayaśirṣapancarātra currently stored in the Bibliotheque Nationale de France.

Comment: The Pāippalāda-saṁhitā́ has been partially scanned and translated 
https://www.atharvaveda-online.uzh.ch/home/paippalada-recension

Answer (score 2):

The Indian government runs a website that has copies of a significant amount of scriptures on the [Vedic Heritage Website](https://vedicheritage.gov.in/) that they run

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Could you elaborate on your answer?